# Security for configuration files

Tags: java, spring-security, configuration, microservices

What are the API which can be used to hide important Service API details from configuration file ? I don't want to expose client id , secrets from the confguration file for calling the APIS ,Can anyone guide here ?

I am trying to hide cliend id and secrets from the configuration file as it is against of security policy. Where can i put all these details ? is there any way to achieve it ?